# Bluetooth not working after upgrading kernel version

Tags: 14.04, kernel, bluetooth

After I upgraded the kernel for my Ubuntu 14.04, from v3.~ to 4.4.0-62-generic the bluetooth is not working anymore and I can't even activate it from the UI.

[image]

I even tested a bluetooth dongle, it's listed on the `lsusb` but no positive results:

```
$ lsusb | grep Blue
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

$ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tested the `hciconfig`, no output

Comment: Does `rfkill unblock all` fail to work?

Comment: @Jeremy31 nothing changes